# What does "Мужики с дрынами" means?

Tags: перевод

Last weekend a read a book where was a sentence: "Из леса вышли мужики с дрынами."
What does "мужики с дрынами" means?

Comment: Have you did any research so far? What did you found? What makes you thing that what you found is still not enough?

Comment: @shabunc [wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BD) lists two meanings for "дрын", so I can understand author's confusion :)

Comment: @Alexander 1) then TS could describe the research he made and specific problem he has. 2) the second meaning is very rare if existing. Sure, any long thing, like banana, can represent penis. So are sticks. But that does not make "penis" a meaning for "banana". 3) The second meaning just makes no sense. "Men with penises walked out of the woods". O'RLY? Who could have guessed! Usually when you see some men walking they do not have any penises, do they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess everyone know what is "мужик", and "дрын" is some wooden stick for a fight, maybe (in a lingo) a rough substitution for a sword among fantasy novels re-enactors.

So, the guys were kind of armed, with what they found in that wood.

Comment: "дрын" is also sometimes used for textolite swords used by LARPers or re-enactors

Comment: Textolite, plywood, cut hockey sticks - any makeshift substitute :-D

Answer (score 1):

[**дрын**](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=%E4%F0%FB%ED) can be translated as **bludgeon**

**мужик** as **man** (folksy for мужчина) or a man of a certain type, **bozo** or [many other variants](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?s=%EC%F3%E6%E8%EA&dstat=%EC%F3%E6%E8%F3&l1=2&l2=1)